# Specific JOIN of 3 tables retrieving data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in MySQL

```
USERS
uid
email
password
created
```

This is the table that have all records of all users

```
PHOTOS
iid
uid
file
thumb
uploaded
```

This is the table where all photos posted by each user are kept on

```
COMMENTS
cid
iid
uid
message
created
```

This is the table where all the comments on each photo by every user are kept on

What i want is a query that retrives me the amount (`COUNT`) of comments on every photo for every unique (`DISTINCT`) user.
For example (the resulting output must be) :

```
comment_amount  by_user on_picture
3               1       1
2               2       1
2               1       2
5               2       2
6               2       3
```

so the output could tell us if it is formated something like (example)

```
3 comments posted by USER1 on PICTURE1
2 comments posted by USER2 on PICTURE1

2 comments posted by USER1 on PICTURE2
5 comments posted by USER2 on PICTURE2

6 comments posted by USER2 on PICTURE3
```

What i have so far is

```
SELECT 
users.uid
FROM users
INNER
    JOIN photos
    ON photos.uid = users.uid
INNER
    JOIN comments
    ON comments.iid = photos.iid
```

and here is the sandbox testing

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/955d5/1
```

But I don't know what to do next. Also any language besides MySQL should work as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) AS comment_amount, users.uid AS by_user, photos.iid AS on_picture
FROM users
INNER
    JOIN photos
    ON photos.uid = users.uid
INNER
    JOIN comments
    ON comments.iid = photos.iid
group by users.uid, photos.iid
```

or just

```
SELECT count(*) AS comment_amount, uid AS by_user, iid AS on_picture
FROM comments
```

if you just need the data in the comments table

Comment: hmmm, this may be it, so this is the solution, with two `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: In order to count comments per user AND photo, you need to group on both parts of "the per".

Comment: And as Gidil says in his answer you don't need the joins if you don't intend to include the user name or any other data from the photos table.

Answer (score 1):

Your query could be like:

```
SELECT users.uid AS UserId, count(comments.cid) AS CountComments
FROM users
INNER
    JOIN photos
    ON photos.uid = users.uid
INNER
    JOIN comments
    ON comments.iid = photos.iid
group by users.uid
```

You can [test it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/955d5/2)

If you want to add an image id you can add photo.iid to group by

```
SELECT users.uid AS UserId, count(comments.cid) AS CountComments, 
  photos.iid as PhotoId
  FROM users
INNER
    JOIN photos
    ON photos.uid = users.uid
INNER
    JOIN comments
    ON comments.iid = photos.iid
group by users.uid, photos.iid
```

[Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/955d5/9)

Comment: i want to count on every photo 3 comments posted by USER1 on PICTURE1
2 comments posted by USER2 on PICTURE1

2 comments posted by USER1 on PICTURE2
5 comments posted by USER2 on PICTURE2

6 comments posted by USER2 on PICTURE3

Comment: You're Welcome. Could you choose the best answer for your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the GROUP first:

```
SELECT  iid, uid, count(*)
FROM comments
GROUP BY  iid, uid
```

and after that join to the relevant tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    users.uid, photos.iid, count(*) nb
    FROM users
    INNER
    JOIN photos
    ON photos.uid = users.uid
INNER
    JOIN comments
    ON comments.iid = photos.iid

group by users.uid, photos.iid
```

Thanks for the sql fiddle link, i didn't know.